# Rule based labels using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I couldn't find an option of "rule-based"-labeling in QGIS 2.10. For example that big cities are also labeled bigger than smaller cities. Am i missing something or doesn't it exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use expressions to define a font size
[image: labels]

For example:

```
CASE 
WHEN "size" > 10 THEN 10 
WHEN "size" > 20 THEN 20
ELSE 30
END
```

Comment: Thank you, solved my problem. Another question: Is it possible to get a dashed underlined Label, for e.g. main cities, but not capital cities. I only see that the normal underlined label is possible.

Comment: No dashed underline I'm afraid.

Comment: Here is an idea to create a dashed underline: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/276450