# Dashed label underline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

Is it possible to create a dashed underline for labeling in QGIS? I have one capital city which for used underline for the name of this city. and now I need dashed underline to a name of the province, how to create dashed underline for the name of the cities in qgis?

Comment: According to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158810/rule-based-labels-using-qgis (bottom comment) dashed underlines are no option in QGIS 2.x. Maybe QGIS 3 can help you out. Or you use the print composer and label each province manually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a workaround for 2.x.

Having a point shape-file with an attribute `city` you can label the cities like:

```
 "city"  || '\n' ||  rpad( '-', length("city") + 5,  '-')
```

**BEST FIT** - additional `lpad` (extend to the left) without addition of a distinct value:

```
"city"  || '\n' ||  rpad('-',length("city"),'-') ||  lpad('-',length ("city"),'-')
```

First argument is the city name, then follows a line break, then we us a hypen and extend (`rpad` and/or `lpad`) it with the length of the city names (`length("city")` and/or add a distinct value to stretch the concatenation of hyphens.

[image]

**EDIT** - Using other Unicode characters

You could also use Unicode symbols directly (see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/90126). Using a `fullwidth hyphen-minus` from http://jkorpela.fi/dashes.html (lowermost entry in the first column of the table), the dashed line looks even better. Just copy/paste it in the Expression Dialog. I've shortened it a little bit (`-2`).

```
"city"  || '\n' ||  rpad('－',length("city")-2, '－')
```

[image]

Label lookalike with `katakana-hiragana double hyphen`:

[image]

Additionally you have to decrease the line height in the `Labels > Formatting`. So the dash line is closer to the city name. Also use `Center` as `Alignment` to center both lines.

Usage in the Layer Properties:

[image]

Result

[image]

I think you have to play around a little bit with the distinct value for stretching the concatenation of hyphens.

**EDIT**

If there is an attributes that distinguish if the city is a capital or not then you can use `Rule-based labeling`.

In my case I have an attribute table as follows:

[image]

Rule-based labeling in this case:

[image]

Result (cities which are not capitals have a normal underline (defined within in the label settings):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can probably achieve it by using an SVG label background (Shape in the dialog) and constructing the SVG in a way that the end result appears as a dashed line.