# QGIS Labeling break underlined

Tags: qgis, labeling

I want to create a labeling for a polygon layer. The labeling should constists two columns from my file, "X" on top, "Y" among "X"and they should be separated through a break underline. Every column contains numbers but not all fields of column "Y" are filled with values. The break underline should only be visible if "X" and "Y" contains a value.

The screenshot shows how the labeling should look like.

[image]

Maybe there is a possibility to create a line over the values of the column "Y", like an underline, but only the opposite position?

Comment: See also: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276443/dashed-label-underline-in-qgis/276450#276450

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I didn't come up with the code, [Claas Leiner](http://www.gkg-kassel.de/fossgiss.html) did and provided it to us.

---

Labelling works as follows:

```
case
when  "nenner" IS NULL then "zaehler" 
Else  "zaehler"  ||'::'||'―' ||':::'||   "nenner" 
end
```

While `"zaehler"` is the "main"-number of the parcel and `"nenner"` the sub-number. So you might need to change the column names.

`:` is the line break sign, line-height is set to 0.25 lines.

---

In order to display the labels in small/thin parcels, you can set the label size dependent on the parcel size:

```
Case
when (  $area  /  $perimeter ) > 8 then 8
when (  $area  /  $perimeter ) < 4 then 3
else round(  $area  /  $perimeter )
End
```

Label size is based on map units, but you can also use pixels. Point-based sizes tend to become a bit too large.

---

And, last but not least, you should consider limiting the scales at which the labels are displayed.

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for your quick and extensive response, but with this code my labeling looks for example like this: 946::-:::1.

Comment: Have you set `:` as the line break sign? `Layer properties - labeling - format` - there you may also set the line height (see my answer).

Comment: Ok, sorry my fault. One last question, how can I create a underline for the "zaehler" which is long enough for all values?

Comment: Though this isn't the "official" display of parcel numbers, you can refer to the question Stefan commented above.